# How to customize legend in MATLAB R2015b?

Tags: matlab-figure

[image]

Desired Legend Layout:
[image]

I am using plot(.) in Matlab to plot following test data

I had 2 cases, each of which is tested for 4 conditions. I am using two markers for represent cases whereas each condition is assigned a distinct color. If I use default legend(.) command in matlab, I end up with 8 entries in legend which I think is a bit redundant.

I would like to have a legend with only 6 entries. Two markers and 4 colors. How can I get that in Matlab? I am open to both single column of double column legend solutions.

MWE:

```
function MinimalExample

MixedShade = [000 000 205; ...  % Medium Blue
              255 064 064; ...  % Brown
              000 233 255; ...  % Aqua
              255 185 015] ...  % Gold
             ./255;

alpha = [0.1:0.1:0.4];        
a = [1*1e0, 1*1e-1, 1*1e-2, 1*1e-3] ;
A = [1*a; 2*a; 3*a; 4*a];
b = [1*1e+1, 1*1e+2, 1*1e+3, 1*1e+4] ;
B = [1*b; 2*b; 3*b; 4*b];

for ii = 1:size(A, 2)
    semilogy(alpha, A(ii, :), 'color', MixedShade(ii, :), 'LineStyle', '-', ...
             'Marker','o', 'MarkerFaceColor', MixedShade(ii, :));
    hold on
end

for ii = 1:size(B, 2)
    semilogy(alpha, B(ii, :), 'color', MixedShade(ii, :), 'LineStyle', '-', ...
             'Marker', '>', 'MarkerFaceColor', MixedShade(ii, :));
    hold on
end

xlabel('$\alpha$', 'Interpreter', 'LaTex'); 
ylabel('$Cost$', 'Interpreter', 'LaTex'); 
grid on 
xlim([0.1 0.4]) 
legend('A,Set1', 'A,Set2', 'A,Set3', 'A,Set4', ...
       'B,Set1', 'B,Set2', 'B,Set3', 'B,Set4', ...
       'location','best');
set(get(gcf,'CurrentAxes'), 'FontName', 'Times', 'FontSize', 14);
```

Comment: Please see: [mcve]. And provide your MATLAB version.

Comment: See edits for MWE

Comment: What is the desired legend for the example case?

Comment: Desired legend layout Posted. ignore the wrong '>' direction. I used paint to draw it so its not very good. But you get an idea of what i am looking for

Comment: And your MATLAB version?

Comment: it is MATLAB R2015b